# Call Remote EJB from WildFly to Glassfish

Tags: java, spring-boot, glassfish, ejb, wildfly-11

I have the next setting:

- An EJB deployed in a glassfish 3.2.1 application Server.
- Trying to deploy a Springboot app as WAR over a Wildfly 11 App Server.

In my springboot app, I added the maven dependency for glassfish client (gf-client):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.main.appclient</groupId>
   <artifactId>gf-client</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to deploy the springboot app in wildfly, the server writes on log the following message:

> [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'TimerBean' in deployment unit 'deployment "gestion-garantias-fcd.war"' are as follows:
>
> java:global/gestion-garantias-fcd/TimerBean!org.glassfish.ejb.persistent.timer.TimerLocal
>       java:app/gestion-garantias-fcd/TimerBean!org.glassfish.ejb.persistent.timer.TimerLocal
>       java:module/TimerBean!org.glassfish.ejb.persistent.timer.TimerLocal
>       java:global/gestion-garantias-fcd/TimerBean
>       java:app/gestion-garantias-fcd/TimerBean
>       java:module/TimerBean
>
> 10:31:38,790 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."gestion-garantias-fcd.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."gestion-garantias-fcd.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "gestion-garantias-fcd.war"
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0041: Component class org.glassfish.ejb.persistent.timer.TimerBean for component TimerBean has errors: 
>   WFLYJPA0033: **Can't find a persistence unit named __EJB__Timer__App in deployment "gestion-garantias-fcd.war"**
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.handle(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:157)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.processClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:186)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:143)
>       at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
>       ... 5 more
>
> 10:31:38,797 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "gestion-garantias-fcd.war")]) - failure description: {
>       "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"gestion-garantias-fcd.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"gestion-garantias-fcd.war\"
>       Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0041: Component class org.glassfish.ejb.persistent.timer.TimerBean for component TimerBean has errors: 
>   WFLYJPA0033: Can't find a persistence unit named __EJB__Timer__App in deployment \"gestion-garantias-fcd.war\""},
>       "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"gestion-garantias-fcd.war\".beanmanager"],
>       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>           "jboss.deployment.unit.\"gestion-garantias-fcd.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"gestion-garantias-fcd.war\".beanmanager]",
>           "jboss.deployment.unit.\"gestion-garantias-fcd.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"gestion-garantias-fcd.war\".beanmanager]"
>       ]
>   }

I bolded what I think is the main cause for the error.

Basically, the error happens because in gf-client exists an internal app called ejb-timer-service-app, and it contains a persistence configuration (persistence.xml). That config specifies a persistence unit called **__EJB__Timer__App**, which references to a datasource which normally is created in all glassfish installations (jdbc/__TimerPool).

I don't know where is that app (ejb-timer-service-app) into gf-client, but I tried to do an exclusion over the gf-client dependency. Exactly, I tried to exclude the next dependency:

```
<groupId>org.glassfish.main.ejb</groupId>
<artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
```

But the error stills present.

Then, I opted for use some individual embeeded dependencies in gf-client. the dependencies list is here:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.deployment</groupId>
            <artifactId>deployment-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-naming</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
           <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.orb</groupId>
            <artifactId>orb-connector</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-container</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

The first error (Can't find a persistence unit..) dessapeared. But now, another error was found:

> Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/gyf_electronicdocument_guaranteeCrediro_ear/gyf_electronicdocument_guaranteeCredioro_business/GuaranteeCOBean!com.gyf.electronicdocument.guaranteeCredioro.to.GuaranteeRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3701, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.ldap.version=3, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=127.0.0.1, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3701, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.ldap.version=3, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=127.0.0.1, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr]]
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:467)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:414)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
>       at com.gyf.gestiongarantias.config.DocumentoElectronicoEJBConfig.ejbWarranty(DocumentoElectronicoEJBConfig.java:40)
>       at com.gyf.gestiongarantias.config.DocumentoElectronicoEJBConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5ce1c3b.CGLIB$ejbWarranty$1()
>       at com.gyf.gestiongarantias.config.DocumentoElectronicoEJBConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5ce1c3b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b2972094.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
>       at com.gyf.gestiongarantias.config.DocumentoElectronicoEJBConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e5ce1c3b.ejbWarranty()
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>       ... 92 more
>
> Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3701, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.ldap.version=3, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=127.0.0.1, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr]
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:310)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:453)
>       ... 107 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr
>       at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:167)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:323)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:330)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:360)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:305)
>       ... 108 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:139)
>       ... 112 more

I tried to use several dependencies for mitigate this error, but I have exhausted my alternatives.

So my questions are:

Should I configurate a persistence unit in my springboot app with the same names like in the persistence.xml?

Is there any dependency that I should exclude?

If gf-client is not the best way, What dependencies of the glassfish repository shoud I use for my case?

Is there any other method for call remote EJB under these conditions exposed in my case?

Thanks in advance, and hope you well.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should create the a persistence unit. I think it needed for gf to run probaly